# Defining path to module's configuration files

Tags: python, configuration, cross-platform

A Python module I'm developing has a master configuration file in `/path/to/module/conf.conf`. The `/path/to/module`/ depends on the platform (for instance, `/Users/me/module` in OS X, `/home/me/module` in Linux, etc).

Currently I define the `/path/to/module` in `__init__.py`, where I use logic:

```
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
 ROOT = '/Users/me/module'
elif sys.platform == 'linux':
 ROOT = '/home/me/module'
# et cetera
```

Once I have the configuration file root directory, I can open `conf.conf` anywhere I want.

Do you have a better methodology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your `__init__.py`, you could get the directory where the `__init_.py` script lives using the `__file__` magic variable like so:

```
from os.path import dirname
ROOT = dirname(__file__)
```

Then you know that `conf.conf` will be located at `os.path.join(ROOT, 'conf.conf')`.